# How to decode octal escapes \303\241 to original utf-8 chars?

Tags: php, encoding

I have a CSV file to import into the database, I found in many places string has encoded in "Mete y S\303\241cala" this manner.

I want to encode it into the original string i.e. "Mete y Sácala".

Reference: https://mothereff.in/utf-8

I have used below function

iconv(mb_detect_encoding("Mete y S\303\241cala", mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8","Mete y S\303\241cala");

this works perfect!

I'm reading a file by ExcelReader and looping the content.

but when I used the actual variable it does not convert it.

// loop

iconv(mb_detect_encoding($rec['title'], mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8",$rec['title']);

Not work with the loop variable, It might be the issue with forward slashes.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279)?

Comment: My DB Collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: Looks like octal byte escapes, so `stripcslashes()`. // Please fix your question title; this is misleading.

Comment: Yes, the original encoding was UTF-8. But clearly high bytes have been converted to C-style escapes. I'd suggest trying things out before relying an flawed assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`stripcslashes()`](http://php.net/stripcslashes) does *not just* strip backslashes, but handles `\r`, `\n` and `\123` character escapes. Because that's clearly what the CSV encoder produced.

> I have used below function
>
> ```
> iconv(mb_detect_encoding("Mete y S\303\241cala", mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8","Mete y S\303\241cala");
> ```
>
> this works perfect!

That's not what's happening there. PHP interprets `\303\241` back to the original string bytes, when it encounters them in a double quotes `"Mete y S\303\241cala"` string expression. Neither `iconv` nor `mb_*` are doing anything here.

In contrast to using a single quoted string `'Mete y S\303\241cala'` or some literal data read from a file. In such cases you'll have to decode the octals yourself (aforementioned function).

Anyway, this isn't "UTF-8 encoded". It's an additional byte sequence encoding atop.

Answer (score 0):

PHP standard library has a solution:

```
$decodedString = utf8_decode($string);
```

Comment: I'm reading a file using ExcelReader and looping the column content and saving into the database.

if I use it like this: utf8_decode($record['title']);. it doesn't work